# Coldfusion jQuery getJSON : Getting WDDX instead of JSON

Tags: jquery, json, coldfusion, wddx

I am using Brian Rinaldi's coldfusion function to convert a dotnet webservice dataset into a structure of queries. Each query is then returned to the client page as JSON to be used in a jQuery function.

The queries are valid query objects. However, JSON is not being returned. Instead I get WDDX as follows:

```
<wddxPacket version='1.0'>
  <header />
  <data>
    <recordset rowCount='31'
    fieldNames='startdate,starttime,subscribercode,dest_number,description,ConnDuration,Callcharge,Usage,ConnType,pages,CallReference,SettingCount'
    type='coldfusion.sql.QueryTable'>
      <field name='startdate'>
        <string>2010-01-30T00:00:00+13:00</string>
        <string>2010-01-29T00:00:00+13:00</string>
      </field>
    </recordset>
  </data>
</wddxPacket>
```

using the following code:

```
function internetUsage(){   
    $.getJSON("system.cfc",{
        method:'getInternetUsage',
        SessionID:$("#vSessionID").val(),
        CustomerCode:$("#vCustomerCode").val(),
        FullUserName:$("#selUser").val(),
        StartDate:$("#vStartDate").val(),
        EndDate:$("#vEndDate").val(),
        returnformat:'json',
        queryformat:'column'
             },function(res,code){

         alert('hello');    // THIS NEVER FIRES!    
    });
}
```

So, I tried getting the CFC to convert the query into JSON and returning the JSON-ified result. This worked a little better in that valid JSON was returned BUT it is still wrapped in `<wddxPacket>` tags, as follows:

```
<wddxPacket version='1.0'><header/><data><string>
{
    "recordcount": 31,
    "columnlist": "callcharge,callreference,connduration,conntype,description,dest_number,pages,settingcount,startdate,starttime,subscribercode,usage",
    "data": [
        {
            "callcharge": "",
            "callreference": "",
            "connduration": 86403,
            "conntype": "UBS",
            "description": "dageorgetti",
            "dest_number": "",
            "pages": "",
            "settingcount": 5,
            "startdate": "2010-01-30T00:00:00+13:00",
            "starttime": "2010-01-30T00:00:00+13:00",
            "subscribercode": "dageorgetti",
            "usage": 33.7300
        }...<snip>...
...<snip>...
</string></data></wddxPacket>
```

The call for achieving the above is as follows:

```
function internetUsage(){   
    $.getJSON("system.cfc",{
        method:'getInternetUsage',
        SessionID:$("#vSessionID").val(),
        CustomerCode:$("#vCustomerCode").val(),
        FullUserName:$("#selUser").val(),
        StartDate:$("#vStartDate").val(),
        EndDate:$("#vEndDate").val(),
        jsonEncode:true // the cfc converts query to JSON
         },function(res,code){

              alert('Hello'); // still not firing       
    });
}
```

I am using returntype="JSON" in the CFC. The cfc is quite complex and I don't think I need to paste it here. I can confirm that it is definitely generating valid query objects, which the conversion function seems to be successfully converting to valid JSON. I don't know why it comes back to the client wrapped in wddxPacket tags.

### EDIT - CFC

```
<cffunction name="invokeInternetUsage" access="remote" returnType="any" output="false">
    <cfargument name="SessionID" required="true">
    <cfargument name="CustomerCode" required="true">
    <cfargument name="FullUserName" required="true">
    <cfargument name="StartDate" required="true">
    <cfargument name="EndDate" required="true">
    <cfset var aTemp = "">
    <cftry>
        <cfinvoke 
            webservice="http://Portal/internet.asmx?WSDL"
            method="Usage"
            returnvariable="aTemp">
                <cfinvokeargument name="SessionID" value="#arguments.SessionID#"/>
                <cfinvokeargument name="CustomerCode" value="#arguments.CustomerCode#"/>
                <cfinvokeargument name="FullUserName" value="#arguments.FullUserName#"/>
                <cfinvokeargument name="StartDate" value="#arguments.StartDate#"/>
                <cfinvokeargument name="EndDate" value="#arguments.EndDate#"/>
        </cfinvoke>
        <cfcatch></cfcatch>
    </cftry>
    <cfreturn aTemp>
</cffunction>


<!--- convertDotNetDataset --->
<cffunction name="convertDotNetDataset" access="remote" returnType="any" output="false"
        hint="takes a .Net dataset and converts it to a CF structure of queries">
<cfargument name="dataset" required="true">
<cfset var Local = StructNew()>
<cfset Local.result = structNew() />
<cfset Local.aDataset = arguments.dataset.get_any() />
<cfset Local.xSchema = xmlParse(Local.aDataset[1]) />
<cfset Local.xData = xmlParse(Local.aDataset[2]) />

<!--- Create Queries --->
<cfset Local.xTables = Local.xSchema["xs:schema"]["xs:element"]["xs:complexType"]["xs:choice"] />
<cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(Local.xTables.xmlChildren)#" index="Local.i">
    <cfset Local.tableName = Local.xTables.xmlChildren[Local.i].xmlAttributes.name />
    <cfset Local.xColumns = Local.xTables.xmlChildren[Local.i].xmlChildren[1].xmlChildren[1].xmlChildren/>
    <cfset Local.result[Local.tableName] = queryNew("") />
    <cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(Local.xColumns)#" index="Local.j">
        <cfif left(Local.xColumns[Local.j].xmlAttributes.name,6) neq 'Column'>
            <cfset queryAddColumn(Local.result[Local.tableName], Local.xColumns[Local.j].xmlAttributes.name, arrayNew(1)) />
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
</cfloop>

<!--- see if there are any row of data, if not exit --->
<cfif NOT StructKeyExists(Local.xData["diffgr:diffgram"], "NewDataSet")>
    <cfreturn Local.result>
</cfif>

<!--- Populate Queries --->
<cfset Local.xRows = Local.xData["diffgr:diffgram"]["NewDataSet"] />
<cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(Local.xRows.xmlChildren)#" index="Local.i">
    <cftry>
<cfset Local.thisRow = Local.xRows.xmlChildren[Local.i] />
        <cfset Local.tableName = Local.thisRow.xmlName />
        <cfset queryAddRow(Local.result[Local.tableName], 1) />
        <cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(Local.thisRow.xmlChildren)#" index="Local.j">
            <cfif left(Local.thisRow.xmlChildren[Local.j].xmlName,6) neq 'Column'>
                <cfset querySetCell(Local.result[Local.tableName], Local.thisRow.xmlChildren[Local.j].xmlName, Local.thisRow.xmlChildren[Local.j].xmlText, Local.result[Local.tableName].recordCount) />
            </cfif>
        </cfloop>
        <cfcatch></cfcatch>
    </cftry>
</cfloop>

<cfreturn Local.result>
```

Comment: So, if you had a .cfm file that just called the system.getInternetUsage method directly, it would correctly get data back in JSON rather than WDDX?

Comment: Yes, if I dump the results directly in a .cfm file, without jQuery, valid JSON is returned with no WDDX wrapper.

Comment: Think posting `system.cfc` would improve your chances of getting an answer. Use http://pastebin.com/ (it has ColdFusion syntax highlighting) and post the link if doing it on SO is too burdensome.

Comment: I've posted the relevant cfc functions. Maybe there's something you can spot.

Comment: Can't your cfc strip out the wddx code from the returning results? to give you the results in a format you want?

Comment: @user460114: Not seeing the `getInternetUsage()` method in the update. Seeing that code as well would help.

Comment: @JamesMohler: Please don't add those minor tags. There are too less people following them, thus it is not sensible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're hand-building JSON, but the cfc method is treating that return value as a string to be wrapped in a WDDX packet. You should try adding `returnformat="plain"` to your cfc method. Also, you're using `.getJSON()`. Instead, use `.get()`.

A quick look at the jQuery source code shows that `getJSON()` is just `get()` with the JSON attribute already hardcoded in:

```
getJSON: function( url, data, callback ) {
  return jQuery.get(url, data, callback, "json");
}
```

Comment: The JSON isn't being handbuilt. I'm hand-building the queries and converting the queries into JSON. I've tried returnformat="plain" with no better results. I've alss tried get() with no better results.

Comment: In your cfc, if you greatly simplify the return value, does it come through as JSON? For example, start with a number, then try an array, then try a (very simple) query.

Comment: Yeah, I've just tried bypassing all the processing and just returning a number and a simple string...and it still comes back wrapped in wddx. Will keep trying...

Comment: OK, I've just realised that this server is running CF7. Should've checked that at the beginning. It always comes back wrapped in wddx. I think I might try a replace() to strip the wddx tags.

Comment: Yeah, that's an oops. You might take a look at this post from [Ray Camden's Blog](http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2010/11/3/Best-JSON-option-for-folks-not-running-ColdFusion-9), including some useful comments.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I have returned JSON data from a CFC my functions tend to look like this:

```
<cffunction name="methodName" access="remote" returnformat="plain" output="false">
<cfset jsonresult = '{
 "somevar1": "val1",
 "somevar2": "val2"}' />

<cfreturn jsonresult/>
```

Comment: Stackoverflow screwed up my code ( and still is) what I mean (and I think I've shown it now) is that I set the return type to plain

Comment: How does your ajax call look?

Comment: I've created a sample for you consisting of an index.htm and a system.cfc - http://pastebin.com/tjudKc43

Answer (score 0):

Try running the CFC through your browser.

I first tried `<cffunction name="myFunction" returnFormat="JSON">` in a CFC and got WDDX, too. Then I changed it to plain and ran it directly through the browser but it returned an error. Then changed to JSON again and checked it with the browser. It returned JSON as expected.